# SQL Pivot Sum number of entries

Tags: sum, pivot

I have a table with the following structure:

```
Name    Code
----    ---
Jonh    A01
Jonh    A02
Jonh    A01
Jonh    A02
Jonh    A03
```

And i need this:

```
Name    A01 A02 A03
----    --- --- ---
Jonh    2   2   1
```

Could you please help me on this?

Comment: What database product are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You need a pivot query, give this a shot:

```
declare @t as table (Name varchar(50), Code varchar(50));

insert @t (Name, Code)
values 
('Jonh', 'A01')
,('Jonh', 'A02')
,('Jonh', 'A01')
,('Jonh', 'A02')
,('Jonh', 'A03');

select Name
    ,A01
    ,A02
    ,A03
from (
    select Name
        ,Code
    from @t
    ) up
PIVOT(COUNT(Code) for Code in (
            A01
            ,A02
            ,A03
            )) as pvt;
```

Comment: Thank you very much agileMike!!

Comment: Glad to help; do you mind marking this as the answer if it suits your needs?